# How does Nagato create and use so many Rinnegan eyes?

Tags: naruto

The corpses that Nagato uses for the Six Paths technique also possess Rinnegan eyes! How did he get so many Rinnegan eyes?

Is it that the corpse used for one of the six paths has a Rinnegan activated by default? Or is it a convention that Kishi has maintained just to picturize and show us the connectivity?

Of course, they aren't true eyes.

> Even when Tobi possessed Rinnegan, his puppets (corpse he used) had both sharingan and Rinnegan! Now, from where did he bring 6 Sharingan eyes and 6 Rinnegans? Definitely they aren't real ones, What kind of Jutsu is that, that makes corpse possess eye technique?

Comment: Good question. I have also had this in mind since long time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rinnegan occurs so rarely that the Sage of Six Paths was considered a myth, so those multiple Rinnegan's are surely not distinct ones.

Nagato's bodies seemingly having their own Rinnegan is an ability provided by the [Six Paths of Pain](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Paths_of_Pain) technique. According to Narutopedia:

> The Six Paths of Pain (ペイン六道, Pein Rikudō) is an Outer Path technique
>   devised by Nagato after being crippled by Hanzō and rendered emaciated
>   from the numerous chakra receivers embedded in his back by the Demonic
>   Statue of the Outer Path. By piercing corpses with chakra receivers, **a
>   wielder of the Rinnegan can manipulate the bodies as though they are
>   their own.**

The article further says:

> Because of the fact that he was crippled, Nagato channelled the
>   abilities of the Six Paths into six different bodies (one ability per
>   body). **The only common features shared by these bodies were the
>   Rinnegan they gained from this technique**, the chakra receivers each
>   were pierced with and their bright orange hair, which had been dyed to
>   match the Deva Path's natural hair colour.

In other words, the multiple Rinnegan's are like "projections" or copies of Nagato's own Rinnegan, transmitted through the chakra rods. This theory can be further confirmed based on the following:

> In Tobi's version of the Six Paths of Pain technique, his six bodies received a Rinnegan and a Sharingan, and he had a Rinnegan and a Sharigan at the time.

Comment: The projection concept also holds up when you look at all the summoned beasts which also have Rinnegan eyes.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there's a wiki for Naruto. Thanks for link. :)

Comment: Without the help of Rinnegan sharingan wouldn't have been casted to puppets isn't it? much satisfsying answer.. Deidara :)

Answer (score 5):

By being under his control, the Rikudo Pain and Animal Path´s summons have fake, but still potent Rinnegan. As we see in the Shinobi World War, when he uses the Rinnegan himself, he does it many times better than the bodies.

Comment: Could you please explain yourself? It isn't incredibly clear.

Comment: Sorry i did put it unclearly. Basically, Nagato´s Chakra influences the bodies that receive it via the Chakra Rods. Because they are corpses, they use his chakra (to which the Rinnegan belongs, as Chakra is basically a methapor for spiritual energy in Hindu). By extension of "belonging" to his chakra, they get the Rinnegan, although a far weaker version. Same goes for his Summons.

Comment: So basically, you're saying that their Rinnegan is a reflection of the one Nagato has?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha If I understand correctly, he meant 'Projection', rather than 'reflection'. What he points out is, the original rinnegan is far more powerful than the projected rinnegans possessed by corps. Evidently it's true, as we watched Nagato fighting Naruto and others when summoned by incarnation, he was hell powerful. Christy didn't choose fit words to express, but he's right..

Comment: @ChristianAurigFrøkjær, rather than calling(in your comment) "'Rikudo pein' are weaker than Nagato".. it's better to say "Nagato's using Rinnegan himself is far stronger than Rikodu Pein"" :)

Answer (score 0):

I will explain this in my words, hopefully in a better and more concise way. Nagato has the Rinnegan. We've learned that the chakra rods transmit chakra (much like Wifi) What gives somebody (most) Kekkai-Genkai's is a genetic difference that causes a change in the natural Yang chakra in the person. (Body Chakra, such as Bone Manipulation and Kekkai Genkais that affect the physical form) Or the Yin Chakra (Haku's Ice Release or Scorch release, releases that allow a different type of Nature release or something similar to be used.) Then there are mixes between the two. (Namely, the Dojutsu. Affecting the physical form with the change and enhancement of the eyes and the special releases that come with them. The Byakugan is more physical (through affecting the physical chakra points and using their Eyes to learn how to use them) while the Sharingan is more mental, or Yin. (Being able to use special abilities such as Amaterasu, Tsukiyomi and other abilities.) Both of these sets of eyes are descendants of the Rinnegan, which affects the Yin and Yang chakras together. (Allowing for physical manipulation through some paths like Chakra Absorption while the Deva path gives a Yin ability that allows for a special form of space-time release.) The Rinnegan requires the genetics of the Uchiha and the Senju together. (Because these are the two brothers of the Sage of Six Paths) The reason why the Bodies resurrected or summoned by the Rinnegan have a lower-powered version of the Rinnegan because they receive the Chakra of Nagato, allowing them to manifest the Yin (Mental) chakra of the Rinnegan, but lacking severely in the Physical. Although the Yin chakra still allows for the manifestation of all of the abilities, they are severely weaker because they lack the Yang (the genetics) of the Rinnegan. Another example of this is in Obito's resurrected corpses. They have the ability to Manifest the Rinnegan and the Sharingan. The Rinnegan is still weaker than the one that Obito has, but the Sharingan isn't AS weakened as the Rinnegan. (This is because the Sharingan is more of a Mental, or Yin ability.) There is a third example of this ability in Sasuke when he received the Sage of Six Paths chakra, thus awakening the Rinnegan inside of himself. (Along with his Uchiha abilities turning the Rinnegan into the tomoed Rinnegan, which compensated for the loss of power in the Rinnegan, giving him an even stronger version due to the fusion.)

Comment: You may like to consider using multiple paragraphs to break up this wall of text.

Answer (score 0):

There is no conclusive answer despite what the above responses would have us believe.  During the dissection of the Path that was in Konoha during the manga we can see that it still has a Rinnegan despite being long dead and the rods being removed.  That doesn't mean they're fully functional in any way but something remains even after that chakra stops transmitting,  It's still likely a technique but it's WAY more complicated than that.