# Could someone transplant the Rinnegan from one of Pain's paths?

Tags: naruto

Could someone transplant the Rinnegan from one of Pain's paths?

For example, from the male Chikoshodo (summoning) Pain that the Leaf had in their possession.

Comment: Excellent question! Kishimoto would have a hard time explaining it. :)

Comment: As Happy put it [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2382/how-does-nagato-create-and-use-so-many-rinnegan-eyes?rq=1),"The multiple Rinnegan's are like 'projections' or copies of [the user's] own Rinnegan, transmitted through the chakra rods." But this does not explain why the Rinnegan remains even when the rods are removed.

Comment: @TAAPSogeking - You've got any references for this sentence, *But this does not explain why the Rinnegan remains even when the rods are removed*. I'd love see that, because I seemed to have missed it.

Answer (score 7):

I have to say NO.

My reasoning is based on the time when Tobi is hunting for the Rinnegan after the death of Nagato. After he kills Konan, he finds the corpses of Yahiko (who was also the Tendo's body) and Nagato, and pulls only the body of Nagato to his dimension and leaves the body of Yahiko in the same place. If he would have been able to use Yahiko's eyes, I reckon Tobi would've picked that body as well. Seeing how he chooses to ignore Yahiko's body would suggest that only Nagato's eye truly matters and it's the real Rinnegan.

Answer (score 3):

**NO**, transplantation of the Rinnegan eyes from one of Pain's paths would not work. As soon as the eyes are detached from the corpse, they lose contact with the chakra receiver rods, and turn back into ordinary eyes that the corpse originally had. In Chapter 565, Naruto and Bee discuss this when they are fighting against Tobi's Six Paths of Pain.

[image: Naruto and Bee discussing strategy against Tobi's Six Paths of Pain]

The Chikoshodo Pain's corpse in Konoha's possession still had the Rinnegan activated, but it also had about 20 chakra rods when Shizune is shown examining it in Chapter 406.<sup>1</sup> We were never shown the corpse's eyes with all the chakra rods removed.

[image: Pain's body with chakra rods and Rinnegan]
[image: Shizune performing medical examination]

---

<sup>1</sup> We have to make an assumption that although the chakra reception weakens over distance, it will not completely die down. Without this, the corpse still having the Rinnegan activated becomes a plot inconsistency, if not a plot hole.